# remove port number 8069 from the url

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost

I am using centos 6. I want to remove the port from url
that is,I want to use `http://www.website.com/` insted of  `http://www.website.com:8069/` so i tried to create the virtualhost.

I opened the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
and added the line

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs"
    ServerName www.website.com
    ServerAlias website.com
    ProxyPass / http://www.website.com:8069/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.website.com:8069/
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted the server

```
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

but its not working

it is not giving any error and nor working

Answer (score 0):

The only solution if you want to use http://www.website.com/ is to open port 80 on the server or server's router.

Answer (score 0):

you should check via netstat if the apache process is listening to port 80 via

```
netstat -tulpn
```

next to check is local firewall. Check with

```
iptables -L
```

if the command lists entries iptables is active. You can turn it of with

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

or add an entry for port 80

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

if that doesn't help you should check the apache logs under

```
/var/log/httpd/
```